# Setting the position of the mouse, raise the click event on a canvas

Tags: wpf, vb.net, canvas

This functionality that I am working now is a little tricky, so I need some help to find the solution.
The thing is that I have to raise the MouseDown event on a canvas from code, and pass the position of the mouse in the canvas, and the rest of parameters.
Is a project in VB.Net, I know that that I don't need the 'Call' keyword, but I keep it just for clarify the code :)
This is the code that I have, but still don't know how pass the mouse position for this call.

```
    Call picture_MouseDown(picture, New MouseButtonEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 0, MouseButton.Left))
```

Lets say that I have the X and Y position on the this two variables:

```
    CInt(XC), CInt(YC)
```

Thank you in advance, I really appreciate any help :)

Comment: Its called hit testing and it works like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hmm, thank you Hedgehog, but still not find the way to do it. I need to pass the position for the X and Y to the event handler.

Comment: You will have to post more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't call event handlers directly.  Instead, separate the functionality that occurs when you click the picture box into a separate method and call the method from both places:

```
Class MainWindow 
    Private Sub Canvas1_MouseDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles Canvas1.MouseDown
        DoSomethingWithCanvas(sender, e.GetPosition(sender), e.ChangedButton)
    End Sub

    Private Sub SomeOtherSub()
        Dim XC As Double = 100.0
        Dim YC As Double = 100.0

        'Do the code that would normally happen if the picturebox was actually clicked.
        DoSomethingWithCanvas(Canvas1, New Point(CInt(XC), CInt(YC)), MouseButton.Left)
    End Sub

    Private Sub DoSomethingWithCanvas(picBox As Canvas, loc As Point, button As MouseButton)
        'Some Code here that manipulates the Canvas
        If button = MouseButton.Left Then
            'Do something for left button click
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```